# fix elf segment address on an objcopy output binary

Tags: code-injection, elf, objcopy, readelf

I'm trying to inject some compiled code into an elf executable. The strategy is to write some bytes at the end of the 'code' segment. The reason why I chose that segment is because I need my payload to be executed too. I'd like to extend the segment by the required amount, when the padding between segments is too small, so that it can host my payload. `objcopy` can do that just fine with `objcopy <exec> --update-section <name>=<file>`.

My host will be section `.fini`, and the section after that one is `.rodata`. After executing objcopy, the code segment's file size and memory image size are the correct amount. Section and segment offsets are also patched when they need to be. And the code is present at the expected offset (confirmed by `objdump`).

My problem is that none of the segments' virtual addresses were patched, which causes the code segment to overlap on the next section/segment, which results in a segfault during `_dl_start` because the code is considered to be in a read-only segment.
Below are some snippets from the output generated by `readelf`.

before objcopy:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [16] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000000a3e84  000a3e84
       0000000000000009  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [17] .rodata           PROGBITS         00000000000a4000  000a4000
       000000000003b488  0000000000000000   A       0     0     32

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000063000 0x0000000000063000 0x0000000000063000
                 0x0000000000040e8d 0x0000000000040e8d  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x00000000000a4000 0x00000000000a4000 0x00000000000a4000
                 0x0000000000043ccc 0x0000000000043ccc  R      0x1000
```

and after:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [16] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000000a3e84  000a3e84
       00000000000002bd  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [17] .rodata           PROGBITS         00000000000a4000  000a5000
       000000000003b488  0000000000000000   A       0     0     32

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000063000 0x0000000000063000 0x0000000000063000
                 0x0000000000041141 0x0000000000041141  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x00000000000a5000 0x00000000000a4000 0x00000000000a4000
                 0x0000000000043ccc 0x0000000000043ccc  R      0x1000
```

my system: `Linux 6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 (2023-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Does anybody know how to further patch the binary to make it functional while still having a valid elf in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anybody know how to further patch the binary to make it functional

This isn't going to work -- you have a *linked* binary, which means the linker has "baked" data addresses into code.

You wish to move data to a different address, but that requires updating all of the "baked in" addresses, and the info (relocations) needed to perform such an update has already been discarded.

What you need to do is add a *new* executable segment (sections don't matter at runtime), and put your payload into that new segment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know of any documentation about this?

Comment: And I suppose I should place this new segment at the end of the file? Because if not, I'd end up having the same issue of having to push back some bytes, right?